# Can I autoplay audio from a user interaction on a previous page on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I have an e-learning course that needs to autoplay audio with an animation on mobile.

I know that for IOS and Android autoplay requires a user interaction.  How can I set it up so that that a click of next button on the previous page of the course will launch the audio on the following page?

Here is code I have tried which works on desktop but seems like the user interaction is lost to mobile OS on the next page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.NavigationButton').on('click touchend', function() {
        //Internal Event that fires once content on next page is loaded
        events.on('content.loaded', function () {
            console.log( "window loaded" );
            $("audio").trigger('play');
        });
    });
});
```

Is what I need to accomplish even possible?

Comment: I doubt it.  Not being able to auto-play media content was a constant point of contention in my last job.  Clients always wanted things to "just play" and we had to tell them, "No it doesn't work like that."  There was a workaround for a short while, but every time someone finds a work around, Apple patches it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this issue using something like

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    yourAudioControl.play();
});

$('#btn').trigger('click');
```

Comment: That will not cause the audio to play on most mobile devices.